# How to calculate FIRST sets by hand

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I don't understand one of the examples provided by my tutor.

Example

```
S ::= aBA | BB | Bc
A ::= Ad | d
B ::= ε
```

We have

```
FIRST(B) = FIRST(ε)
         = {ε}

FIRST(A) = FIRST(Ad) ∪ FIRST(d)
         = FIRST(A) ∪ {d}
         = {d}

FIRST(S) = FIRST(aBA) ∪ FIRST(BB) ∪ FIRST(Bc)
         = FIRST(a) ∪ (FIRST(B)\{ε}) ∪ FIRST(B) ∪ (FIRST(B)\{ε) ∪ FIRST(c)
         = {a, ε, c}
```

Why is there a FIRST(B) in the FIRST(S) calculation? Shouldn't it be

```
(FIRST(B)\{ε)?
```

Why is A missing from FIRST(S) calculation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This page](http://www.jambe.co.nz/UNI/FirstAndFollowSets.html) gives the mechanical rules for deriving FIRST (and FOLLOW) sets. I'll try to explain the logic behind these rules and how they apply to your example.

#### FIRST sets

`FIRST(u)` is the set of terminals that can occur first in a full derivation of `u`, where `u` is a sequence of terminals and non-terminals. In other words, when calculating the `FIRST(u)` set, we are looking only for the terminals that could possibly be the first terminal of a string that can be derived from `u`.

#### FIRST(aBA)

Given the definition, we can see that `FIRST(aBA)` reduces to `FIRST(a)`, then to `a`. This is because no matter what the `A` and `B` productions are, the terminal `a` will always occur first in anything derived from `aBA` since `a` is a terminal, and can't be removed from the front of that sequence.

#### FIRST(Bc)

I'm going to skip `FIRST(BB)` for now and move on to `FIRST(Bc)`. Things are different here, since `B` is a non-terminal. At first, we say that anything in `FIRST(B)` is also in `FIRST(S)`. Unfortunately, `FIRST(B)` contains `ε` which causes problems, as we could have the scenario

```
   FIRST(Bc)
-> FIRST(εc)
=  FIRST(c)
=  c
```

where the arrow is a possible derivation/reduction. In general, we therefore say that `FIRST(Xu)`, where `ε` is in `FIRST(X)`, is equal to `(FIRST(X)\{ε}) ∪ FIRST(u)`. This explains the last two terms in your calculation.

#### FIRST(BB)

Using the above rule, we can now derive `FIRST(BB)` as `(FIRST(B)\{ε}) ∪ FIRST(B)`. Similarly, if we were calculating `FIRST(BBB)` we would reduce it as

```
  FIRST(BBB)
= (FIRST(B)\{ε}) ∪ FIRST(BB)
= (FIRST(B)\{ε}) ∪ (FIRST(B)\{ε}) ∪ FIRST(B)
```

Of note is that while calculating a FIRST set, the last symbol in a sequence of symbols never has the empty string removed from it, because at this point, the empty string is a legitimate possibility. This can be seen in a possible derivation in your example:

```
   S
-> BB
-> εε
-> ε
```

---

Hopefully you can see from all of the above why `FIRST(B)` appears in your calculation while `FIRST(A)` does not.